# Form of SM hypercharge current and anomalies

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, standard-model, higgs, quantum-anomalies

I have a doubt regarding the SM hypercharge current associated with the $U(1)_Y$ global symmetry (note: I want to work in the unbroken phase, we have the doublet H and the Yukawas)

$\psi \to e^{i\alpha Y_{\psi}}\psi, \psi=Q,u,d.$

The hypercharge values $Y_{\psi}$ are fixed by demanding the SM to be anomaly free. Typically, the hypercharge current is expressed as

$J^{\mu}_Y= \sum_{\psi}Y_{\psi}j_{\psi}^{\mu}, \quad\psi=Q,u,d$

where I have defined $j_{\psi}^{\mu}\equiv \bar{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}\psi$. See, for example, Schwartz's book eq (29.42). My first question is: isn't this current actually incomplete? As far as I can tell one would also need to consider the Higgs, as it is charged under hypercharge. Considering this, and using Noether's theorem, I think the hypercharge current is given by

$J^{\mu}_{Y}=\sum_{\psi}Y_{\psi}j_{\psi}^{\mu}+\left(\partial H^{\dagger}\right) H-\left(\partial H\right) H^{\dagger}, \psi=Q,u,d$

When writing the Lagrangian, we have the option to either write the kinetic Higgs term with the covariant derivative or to split/expand it and couple the EW bosons to the Higgs part of the above current. So, from a Lagrangian point of view it does not matter as we are just writing the same in a different manner. But, if the above current is correct, my follow up question is, why does the Higgs part never appear when we talk about the SM anomalies? Is it simply that the Higgs part is always conserved (on-shell), and thus only the fermionic part violates the symmetry? Notice how then the hypercharge values fixed by demanding an anomaly free theory correspond to the fermions, but not to the Higgs, for which we can fix its hypercharge demanding the invariance of the Yukawa terms. Am I missing something, or is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Do you appreciate gauge anomalies do not arise from boson loops and are traceable to ambiguities in the fermionic measure in the path integral?  You may have answered your own question. Indeed, the currents have a boson piece so the charges transform bosons, but there are no quantum corrections to the divergence of such pieces.

Comment: Hi, yeah I know they come from the non-invariance of the fermionic measure of the path integral. Thanks, all makes sense, just wanted to be sure.